# Arch(Antergos) and i386-efi grub

Tags: arch-linux, grub2

Hi i have a little problem i wanna to change Ubuntu to Antergos Linux but from Ubuntu 15.04 Ubuntu cab install i386-efi grub and my tablet will work all right but arch (Antergos) didn't automatically do it and even when i give it EFI partition and says to install i386-efi version it don't and says that it cannot find "root-image" i don't know what to do. Even when i open EFI partition in windows and open ubuntu folder inside it has lot of files including bootia32.efi but antregos_grub folder only have grubx64.efi inside and when i had Ubuntu installed i installed windows update which broke my grub so what to do how to install i386-efi grub ?
DEVICE: Lenovo Miix 3-830
64bit processor with 32bit uefi (Don't ask me why they do this stupid thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by installing ubuntu 17.04 which can install `i386-efi` grub OK and copied `i386-efi` folder from /boot/grub to backup USB then installed Antergos and copied it back to /boot/grub then selected Ubuntu in UEFI boot menu and i was welcomed with awesome Antergos GRUB.